# Какая речевая погрешность?

Tags: лексика

Что же не так в этом предложении: 
Профессиональные препараты Villa Borghini – все для лечения кожи головы и волос.

Answer (score 4):

Нужно переставить слова:  Профессиональные препараты Villa Borghini – все для лечения волос и кожи головы. А то получается кожи (головы и волос).

Answer (score 0):

Я бы еще двоеточие поставила вместо тире. А то странный смысл получается: наши препараты - это все лекарства для волос, других не существует.